# Spring JPA Exception during recursive

Tags: spring, jpa

I have the following columns

```
ID username placementID sponsorID
4   G1             3       3
5   G2             4       4
6   G3             5       5
3   mzys        null    null
```

I am trying to use JPA to count how many users are on the 3rd generation of `mzys`.

The answer should be one because mzys > G1 > G2 > G3

However when I use

```
userRepository.countByPlacementPlacementPlacementUsername(placementPlacementPlacement.getUsername())
```

It gives me

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.bind(CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.java:63)
```

**UPDATE**

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User extends BasePersist<UserBO> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PLACEMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = true)
    private User placement;

    ...
```

Now I am trying to write my own query with

```
@Query(value="select count(u.id) from User u "
            + "left join u.placement u1 on u.placement.id = u1.placement.id "
            + "left join u.placement u2 on u1.placement.id = u2.placement.id "
            + "left join u.placement u3 on u2.placement.id = u3.placement.id "
            + "where u3.username =?1 and deletedflag =?2")
    int countByPlacementPlacementPlacementUsername(String username, boolean deletedFlag);
```

and I get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements
```

Any idea why this is happening ? Is there better way to achieve what I need ?

Comment: Could be that you don't specify exact entity for deletedflag property

Comment: I had to change it to `u3.deletedFlag`. However that wasn't the main culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was with `ON` word. After I removed it the problem went away.

```
@Query(value="select count(u.id) from User u "
            + "left outer join u.placement u1 "
            + "left outer join u.placement u2 "
            + "left outer join u.placement u3 "
            + "where u3.username =?1 and u3.deletedFlag =?2")
    int countByPlacementPlacementPlacementUsername(String username, boolean deletedFlag);
```